# Combining Entity Framework SqlQuery with extra restriction in code

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a SQL query

```
var sql = "Select * From Foo Where Bar = {0}"
```

I want to execute this using Entity Framework, but I want to impose an extra restriction, to see if column Id is in a certain range:

```
List<int> ids = ...;
var MyFoos = context.Foos.SqlQuery<Foo>(sql).Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));
```

Is this likely to result in efficient selection from the database, or would it end up executing the whole of "Select * From Foo Where Bar = {0}" first and only then filtering for the IDs?

Comment: My expectation would be the latter, because the query is hardcoded rather than something generated by EF itself, and thus there is no way for compilation to improve the query into a single sql read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL statement in `sql` will be executed database side, and results will be returned to the client.

The filter `.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));` will then be executed against the results of your `sql` query, client side.

The `.Where` will not be translated to SQL.

I verified this using [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx) on a similar query.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely avoid doing that then!